# @chatbase Error with not handled function in node mode

Tags: chatbase

I am trying to connect my bot with chatbase. 
For that I have generated the API key and connected it with after that I have set my intent with function `sendChatbaseHandledMessage` and `sendChatbaseNotHandledMessage`.

While I use `sendChatbaseNotHandledMessage` it gives this error:

```
The message cannot be set as not_handled and not be of type user.
at MessageStateWrapper.exportCreatePayload (/home/runner/node_modules/@google/chatbase/lib/MessageSink.js:426:14)
at Promise (/home/runner/node_modules/@google/chatbase/lib/MessageStateWrapper.js:145:29)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at MessageStateWrapper.send (/home/runner/node_modules/@google/chatbase/lib/MessageStateWrapper.js:141:12)
at sendChatbaseNotHandledMessage (evalmachine.<anonymous>:36:143)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:39:3
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:74:29)
at Object.runInContext (vm.js:182:6)
at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
```

As I can understand, the issue is with the chatbase node_modules with some library.
Can I get some solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Reposting the response from our engineer to the internal thread for reference.

It looks like the error is:
message cannot be set as not_handled and not be of type user
Not handled messages in the chatbase API can only by of type user so one would need to say:

var msg = chatbase.newMessage('my-api-key', 'my-user-id')
msg.setAsTypeUser().setAsNotHandled().send()...

In the chatbase API one cannot set agent messages as not handled, so the following is not allowed:
msg.setAsTypeAgent().setAsNotHandled()